# Chrome opening further down screen each time

Tags: applications, desktop, google-chrome

I have been using Elementary OS for a few months now. Am really enjoying using it.

1 problem I have tho is that I use Google Chrome for browsing and I have made web apps with it for Facebook, Instagram etc and after using it then closing it, the next time I open it, it opens up a little bit further down on the screen.

This happens every time until the bottom of the window gets to the bottom of the screen and then it doesn't get any lower. So I move the window back up the top and it all starts again. Any ideas?

*Happens using Chromium too

Comment: Do you use a laptop? Maybe you left your trackpad enabled and that's causing this...

Comment: No, no laptop. Using a desktop machine.